# Vue+Webpack configuration

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I try to use Vue2 with Webpack4. Command webpack-dev-server finished with success, but it shows me only folders:
[image]

My webpack.config.js is:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    publicPath: './',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'result.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 8532,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'vue-style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "public/fonts")],
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      minify: false,
    })
  ],
};
```

This is my first experience with Vue.
What am I doing wrong?
Before that I tried to use vue-cli, but as I understood I can't use scss and Pug without Webpack.
Am I right?

Comment: you could use `scss` and `pug` in vue cli

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  for this I need to create a separate configuration file?

Comment: for scss you don't need that but for pug you need

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim can you explain how to do it?

Comment: Try to follow this tuto https://dev.to/patarapolw/working-with-pug-and-markdown-in-vue-cli-3c9j